# 2000 Lexus ES300, 3rd brake light is out

Tags: toyota, tail-lights, lexus

I have a 2000 Lexus ES300. Recently, while someone else was in possession of my car, they caused some issues when they ran my new battery dead and then  jump started it backwards, shorting out my alternator and alternator fuse.

After replacing these I noticed that the light illuminated on my dash indicating I had two burnt out rear bulbs, it was my 3rd brake light which is located in with my regular brake lights and tail lights (not above in the rear window).

I replaced these bulbs (both were blown), however the light came back on. I rechecked the bulbs and they are good. I am unable to locate a fuse that could control just the third brake light. Every fuse I have checked looks good.

Does anyone have any knowledge of what this could be that can help me out? I'd greatly appreciate any input! Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Do the lights turn on when the brake light is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your third brake light is located with the other brake lights, unless this is a non-US spec vehicle, or perhaps some sort of convertible.

The Center High Mounted Stop Lamp or CHMSL is exactly that.  It must be high and centered, defined by agreed-upon SAE specifications.

Are you certain there isn't a light on the rear parcel shelf?  I believe in order to replace that bulb, you have to undo screws from inside the trunk, and then the light can be pried carefully off the rear shelf from inside the vehicle.